# SVG анимация грузовика

Tags: html, svg

Необходимо, чтобы у грузовика двигались колёса и он сам ездил.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->

<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="612px" height="612px" viewBox="0 0 612 612" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 612;" xml:space="preserve" sodipodi:docname="delivery23.svg"
  inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"><metadata
       id="metadata41"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
           rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
             rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
       id="defs39" /><sodipodi:namedview
       pagecolor="#ffffff"
       bordercolor="#666666"
       borderopacity="1"
       objecttolerance="10"
       gridtolerance="10"
       guidetolerance="10"
       inkscape:pageopacity="0"
       inkscape:pageshadow="2"
       inkscape:window-width="1920"
       inkscape:window-height="1001"
       id="namedview37"
       showgrid="false"
       inkscape:zoom="0.38562092"
       inkscape:cx="306"
       inkscape:cy="306"
       inkscape:window-x="-9"
       inkscape:window-y="-9"
       inkscape:window-maximized="1"
       inkscape:current-layer="Capa_1" />
    <g
       id="g4"
       transform="matrix(0.47033898,0,0,0.47033898,2.5932203,84.087922)">
     <path
       d="M 21.474,377.522 V 117.138 c 0,-14.469 11.729,-26.199 26.199,-26.199 h 260.25 c 14.469,0 26.198,11.73 26.198,26.199 v 260.385 c 0,4.823 -3.909,8.733 -8.733,8.733 H 30.207 c -4.824,0 -8.733,-3.91 -8.733,-8.734 z m 210.16,89.202 c 0,30.01 -24.329,54.338 -54.338,54.338 -30.009,0 -54.338,-24.328 -54.338,-54.338 0,-30.011 24.329,-54.338 54.338,-54.338 30.009,0 54.338,24.327 54.338,54.338 z m -27.17,0 c 0,-15.005 -12.164,-27.169 -27.169,-27.169 -15.005,0 -27.17,12.164 -27.17,27.169 0,15.005 12.165,27.17 27.17,27.17 15.005,0 27.169,-12.165 27.169,-27.17 z M 130.495,412.385 H 8.733 C 3.91,412.385 0,416.295 0,421.118 v 26.495 c 0,4.823 3.91,8.733 8.733,8.733 h 97.598 c 2.548,-17.484 11.373,-32.928 24.164,-43.961 z m 385.443,54.339 c 0,30.01 -24.329,54.338 -54.338,54.338 -30.01,0 -54.338,-24.328 -54.338,-54.338 0,-30.011 24.328,-54.338 54.338,-54.338 30.009,-0.001 54.338,24.327 54.338,54.338 z m -27.168,0 c 0,-15.005 -12.165,-27.169 -27.17,-27.169 -15.006,0 -27.169,12.164 -27.169,27.169 0,15.005 12.164,27.17 27.169,27.17 15.005,0 27.17,-12.165 27.17,-27.17 z M 612,421.118 v 26.495 c 0,4.823 -3.91,8.733 -8.733,8.733 h -70.704 c -5.057,-34.683 -34.906,-61.427 -70.961,-61.427 -36.062,0 -65.912,26.745 -70.969,61.427 H 248.261 c -2.549,-17.483 -11.373,-32.928 -24.164,-43.961 H 359.091 V 162.594 c 0,-9.646 7.82,-17.466 17.466,-17.466 h 82.445 c 23.214,0 44.911,11.531 57.9,30.77 l 53.15,78.721 c 7.796,11.547 11.962,25.161 11.962,39.094 v 118.672 h 21.253 c 4.823,0 8.733,3.91 8.733,8.733 z M 523.408,256.635 480.907,196.242 c -1.636,-2.324 -4.3,-3.707 -7.142,-3.707 H 407.47 c -4.822,0 -8.733,3.91 -8.733,8.733 v 60.393 c 0,4.824 3.91,8.733 8.733,8.733 h 108.798 c 7.074,0 11.212,-7.973 7.14,-13.759 z"
       id="path2"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </g>
    <g
       id="g6">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g8">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g10">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g12">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g14">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g16">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g18">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g20">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g22">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g24">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g26">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g28">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g30">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g32">
    </g>
    <g
       id="g34">
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А это ваш SVG я его почистил от лишнего и добавил smil - **исправлено**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 612 612" style="display: none;">
<g id="track">
  
 <circle cx="177" cy="467" r="58" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="10 10 10">
   <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" 
                     from="0 177 467" to="360 177 467" dur="20s" 
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
 <circle cx="461.5" cy="467" r="58" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="10 10 10">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" 
                     from="0 461.5 467" to="360 461.5 467" dur="20s" 
                     repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  
 <path
   d="M 21.474,377.522 V 117.138 c 0,-14.469 11.729,-26.199 26.199,-26.199 h 260.25 c 14.469,0 26.198,11.73 26.198,26.199 v 260.385 c 0,4.823 -3.909,8.733 -8.733,8.733 H 30.207 c -4.824,0 -8.733,-3.91 -8.733,-8.734 z m 210.16,89.202 c 0,30.01 -24.329,54.338 -54.338,54.338 -30.009,0 -54.338,-24.328 -54.338,-54.338 0,-30.011 24.329,-54.338 54.338,-54.338 30.009,0 54.338,24.327 54.338,54.338 z m -27.17,0 c 0,-15.005 -12.164,-27.169 -27.169,-27.169 -15.005,0 -27.17,12.164 -27.17,27.169 0,15.005 12.165,27.17 27.17,27.17 15.005,0 27.169,-12.165 27.169,-27.17 z M 130.495,412.385 H 8.733 C 3.91,412.385 0,416.295 0,421.118 v 26.495 c 0,4.823 3.91,8.733 8.733,8.733 h 97.598 c 2.548,-17.484 11.373,-32.928 24.164,-43.961 z m 385.443,54.339 c 0,30.01 -24.329,54.338 -54.338,54.338 -30.01,0 -54.338,-24.328 -54.338,-54.338 0,-30.011 24.328,-54.338 54.338,-54.338 30.009,-0.001 54.338,24.327 54.338,54.338 z m -27.168,0 c 0,-15.005 -12.165,-27.169 -27.17,-27.169 -15.006,0 -27.169,12.164 -27.169,27.169 0,15.005 12.164,27.17 27.169,27.17 15.005,0 27.17,-12.165 27.17,-27.17 z M 612,421.118 v 26.495 c 0,4.823 -3.91,8.733 -8.733,8.733 h -70.704 c -5.057,-34.683 -34.906,-61.427 -70.961,-61.427 -36.062,0 -65.912,26.745 -70.969,61.427 H 248.261 c -2.549,-17.483 -11.373,-32.928 -24.164,-43.961 H 359.091 V 162.594 c 0,-9.646 7.82,-17.466 17.466,-17.466 h 82.445 c 23.214,0 44.911,11.531 57.9,30.77 l 53.15,78.721 c 7.796,11.547 11.962,25.161 11.962,39.094 v 118.672 h 21.253 c 4.823,0 8.733,3.91 8.733,8.733 z M 523.408,256.635 480.907,196.242 c -1.636,-2.324 -4.3,-3.707 -7.142,-3.707 H 407.47 c -4.822,0 -8.733,3.91 -8.733,8.733 v 60.393 c 0,4.824 3.91,8.733 8.733,8.733 h 108.798 c 7.074,0 11.212,-7.973 7.14,-13.759 z"/>
  

</g>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1600 612" id="new">
  <use href="#track" x="0" y="-100" >
    <animate attributeName="x"
             dur="6s"
             begin="0s"
             values="0; 100; 200; 100; 0"
             repeatCount="1"
             fill="freeze"/>
    
      <animate attributeName="y"
             dur="6s"
             begin="0"
             values="-40;-100;-40"
             repeatCount="indefinite"
             fill="freeze"/>
  </use>

</svg>
```

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы у него двигались колёса как на примере выше?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду ждать.

Comment: Мне нужно именно картинку загрузить

Comment: Которую я загрузила, именно с этой надо

Comment: @АнастасияКауноваИТ-192  исправил - проверьте

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!